# "Key is invalid" message on GitHub

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have generated SSH keys for a new server installation according to the procedure outlined [here](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/). However, when I copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to my keys list on GitHub, I get the error message "Key is invalid. Ensure you've copied the file correctly."

The generated key *is* valid, and I am copying it exactly as is (all in one line with no whitespace at the beginning/end).

Anybody have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: Just to be sure, you did include the `ssh-rsa` that comes before the key itself, yes?

Comment: At least in CentOS 7.x , if you generate your SSH key using just `ssh-keygen` then the format won't work. I got this message `Key is not in OpenSSH format`. I fixed it using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` , then copy this key to Github `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I came here because I had the same problem. From your question, I realized that I was copying the contents from the wrong file, *without* the `.pub` extension (it was my private key, i.e. the `id_rsa` file, which should be kept private at all times!)

**From a MAC:**

```
vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy exactly from the end (with be the last letter of your email domain extension) of the block of characters to the beginning, which starts with *ssh-rs ...*

If it doesn't work, you are surely not copying properly.

It worked.

If you are on **Windows**, use notepad and copy-paste as described above.

I hope that helped.

Comment: For a very obscure reason, copy-pasting from emacs removed the \n after ssh-rsa, and that was causing the problem. Copy-pasting from vi solved the problem. Since you gave me the idea of trying that, I'll award the answer to you!

Comment: vi didn't work for me. I had to use the cat command (OSX) to print it to the terminal and copy its output. Thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: copying out of vim worked for me, but copying the result of cat filename didn't

Comment: For whatever reason, my vim was failing to wrap the key. Copied out of sublime to get the whole key. Worked.

Comment: `vi` did the trick, I used nano, which the file is being truncated with `$` symbol

Comment: Same here, using `nano` failed and led to the above-mentioned error; but using `vi` simply worked.

Comment: Jeremiah saved me! I had spent days to resolve this issue but couldn't. Copying the SSH key in clipboard is the real trick and the best way to do it is copying it right from terminal and not notepad or anyother tool etc.

Comment: @Jeremiah You said, that works for me on mac. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub Thanks!

Comment: I had an issue in which the KDE terminal (Konsole) displayed the key in multiple lines, adding a breaking space that wasn't there originally, when copying. Just watch for that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shailen this worked for me like a charm. +1 to you

Answer (score 81):

Here are some steps that are not at all clear when copy/pasting your public key. (For the record, I used Putty Key Generator for my keys.)

- On the first line, enter ssh-rsa.
- Make sure you add one space after ssh-rsa
- When you copy/paste the key into the Key textbox it should preserve the \n characters (x0A). If you are using Notepad on Windows, you won't see these new lines until you copy the text to Github.

Notice on this screenshot, there's a space after ssh-rsa (See the cursor.) The public key text also includes three \n characters, so you can see the public key text bumps down to the next line three times in the textbox.[image: SSH RSA Key]

Comment: My id_rsa.pub file was missing the "ssh-rsa" part. Adding it manually on Github did the trick.

Comment: On a related note, in GitLab (tested 7.4.3), SSH keys can only be added when (as suggested above) adding `ssh-rsa` and by _not_ including the new-line characters.

Comment: This must be a putty specific issue; I had the same error with putty

Comment: @JamesLawruk BTW, GitHub (and, I believe, any ssh-using program) ignores all newline chars in the key file. (That's the reason you're *allowed* to split it into 3 lines --- at rather arbitrary points.)

Comment: adding "ssh-rsa " with one space after that helped me. thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a key created by puttygen, you can use puttygen to load the key and then copy the public key text from there.  Otherwise you'll have to manipulate the contents of the file to get it in the format above.

Comment: In my case, there are some blanks preceding the line change, and that made the copy and pasting not work.

Answer (score 29):

I know this is question is a cpl years old now, but if someone in 2018 encounter this:
[image]

then below is a no-brainer:

my problem was I tried to copy the **private key**

> id_rsa

instead of **public key** content

> id_rsa.**pub**

as my SSH gitlab repository key, so after you:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email.com" -b 4096
```

please remember about the **.pub** file extension to copy from:

- *OSX*:

pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.**pub**

- *Linux*:

xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.**pub**

- *Windows PowerShell*

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.**pub** | clip

then paste it to your gitlab/github or other repository as your SSH key

this makes perfect sense, because you should always only share your public key, not the private one :)

Comment: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` helped, obviously you can leave out `-C your@email.com`

Comment: i love you. I have been trying to get this for hours and this answer was the only one that helped me :)

Answer (score 23):

I try several ways, but none of them helps(my os is ubuntu). Then I thought if I can print the content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub by using command "more".

I sorry than I have no reputation to post images! when i have, i will post it!

Here is a url where you can see the image:

[image]

I copied the content from the command line, and it WORKED!!!

Comment: Post the image url, some user may add it to the body for you.

Comment: upload images on some site and share links.to solve the question

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  I have shared the url. Just copy the content and it will work!

Comment: @Hamad I have shared the url.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed work... everybody has their own theories. Things should not be this 'magical' when it comes to something like SSH keys. What a train wreck adding SSH keys is on github.

Answer (score 7):

Someone suggested to use  `$ vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` however it didn't work for me.

So instead of that ,  I used `$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` command on windows machine to print out on the terminal then copy it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have indeed copied the content of your `id_rsa.pub` key (in one continuous line), the result should look like (from The [GitHub ssh help page](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/#_set_up_ssh_keys)):

[image: ssh key]

The [OP louism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062679/louism) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476360/key-is-invalid-message-on-github/20143785#comment13587458_10485316) a copy-paste issue:

> - For a very obscure reason, **copy-pasting from emacs removed the `\n` after ssh-rsa**, and that was causing the problem.
> - **Copy-pasting from vi solved the problem**.

Answer (score 3):

Just for those looking in the future, another common issue is that word-wrapping.  For example, if you run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` it could wrap lines, thus adding extra `\` characters at each line break.  Remove these and your key should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

*[Recommended](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)* by **GitHub**

## Copying the `SSH-KEY` :

I worked with `xclip` to copy the `id_rsa.pub` key, like so:

### 1. Install `xclip`

`sudo apt-get install xclip`

### 2. Copy with `xclip`

`xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

---

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

In windows,

Just Copy the naked key data from key file and **remove new lines.**
Write this below things in dialogue box to solve your problem.
ssh-rsa Key

**NOTE : There is space between ssh-rsa and key**

And you are done.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, despite copying the public key from `cat` output directly from the terminal (Cmder/ConEmu). It seems that the method that you use to copy the public key seems to make a difference. Here is a way to check:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
4096 SHA256:...
```

Then paste the key that fails into a new file, and try to verify that:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f test.pub
test.pub is not a public key file.
```

In my case I had been copying the key from terminal output using `cat`; instead getting the key from `vim` worked. Here is way to open the key in vim with word wrap enabled:

```
$ vim "+set wrap" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I suspect that the terminal emulator *may* have something to do with it as I haven't had this issue with Terminal.app.

Comment: It worked for me: Putty SSH from Windows to Linux, open key file with vi, then copy from putty by selecting on screen and pasting it. Weird cat didn't work.

Comment: Used puttygen which gave me the full line, not some pub file I had lying around.

Answer (score 2):

If you use putty (puttygen), copy this!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's common issue we face while generating the key. While the SSH generating, we will get two diff files one is id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. here the file with pub extension is the public key holder file. You must copy the content from this file and add to the Github.

NOTES:
1. public key file content starts with 'SSH-RSA'
2. end with your Github email id. ex: if you registered Github with @gmail.com then the pub file has the specified email id at the last

Answer (score 1):

My laptop is on macOS Big Sur version 11.3.1 and the `ssh-keygen -t rsa` generated a very long key with ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com at the beginning.
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` worked; it created a key with ssh-rsa algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using window OS and for some reasons it's doesn't work for me:

```sh
$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
bash: clip: command not found
```

---

I located the hidden `.ssh` folder at addess: `C:\Users\g1100_000\.ssh`
You will see the pub file as below:

[image]

Open it with your code editor and simply copy the key to github.
Hope this can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

On `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` I did something like this:

1. Terminal type: `ssh-keygen`, this will automatically create code, if you do not want to set any passcode, key pressing enters. The code will be in
   `/home/computer_name/.ssh/id_rsa`
2. Type `vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, you will see the SSH key and copy it

```
ssh-rsa 
blablablaUSERNAME@ComputerName
```

4. go to `github account setting >> SSH and GPU keys >> New SSH key >> (without title, title did not work for me)` and paste

Hope it will help someone in the future. For more details see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you using Sublime you can see ssh-key correctly. 
Check if there is any id_rsa.pub

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

If it is in place open it with sublime text

```
sudo subl /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then copy and paste your public ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add an extra white rule after my e-mail (after the entire key string) before it got accepted. I found this out by accident, after trying to copy my ssh key as entered on Gitlab.

pbcopy from my pub key straight form the command line didn't work. The copy from gitlab with the extra white rule at the end, did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. Super frustrating. I figured my situation might have affected the casue of the problem. I am using a tablet, trying to setup the key on githubs site through my tablet browser (Chrome) and I am copying the key from an ssh app connected to my remote linux server.

What ended up happening is that somehow when I copied the key to the browser, it introduced a number of line breaks. Not only that, but it also removed a character from each point where a new line was inserted.

So to get it to work, I had to manually find each new line break, then hunt for that part of the key to find the missing character. I then added the character and removed the new line. After I hunted down each and every change, the key worked fine.

By the way, I did not add any new line breaks myself, such as the one mentioned by others after the ssh-rsa.

Hopefully this helps others. I have no idea why it happened. Silly that copying to the clipboard would alter the text copied. Oh, I also copied it right out of Vim.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash for windows as your terminal and you are copying via shift + highlighting + ctrl-c, then this solution might work for you:

1. After copying the key and pasting it into notepad:

[image: example ssh key]

2. Now go to Edit > Select All or Ctrl-A

[image: text highlighted]

3. The large amounts of blue areas are whitespace.  You need to delete them with either the backspace or the delete key.  Leave the whitespace that in the green circles.

[image]

4. You should now be able to copy and paste this edited version into github.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if using vs code

`code ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

will open `.pub` file copy it to github

Answer (score 0):

To Copy the entire content of id_rsa.pub to clipboard:

Run >  `pbcopy  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to upload my public key and was getting "Invalid Key" message.My format was not proper as there was extra spaces at the end of the key. It should be in format : `ssh-rsa <public-key>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux or mac, just do the following:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The output should be in the form like below:

```
ssh-rsa somerandomcharacters user@domain
```

Final step is to copy the contents and paste it in your destination

Answer (score 0):

Copying the ssh public key into clipboard is mainly the trick here and the best way to do it is right from terminal. **You must output this key onto the terminal by following command** `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.public` and press enter. The ssh public will be displayed on the GitBash terminal screen and then you just need to copy it carefully by **selecting from last charachter of your email to the begining of key i.e ssh rsa...**
I spent days and then came to this solution in end.

Answer (score 0):

$ cat /c/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
use this command instad of $ cat /c/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

My answer only applies to PuTTY Key generator and Bitbucket repo. You can generate the key pair in few other ways, see other answers.

Use Putty Key Gen to create RSA key with 2048 bits or higher. Private key can be password protected or not. Once two keys (files) are generated, the tool displays your public key **in the upper window**. Here is an example of my key, scraped for security. Notice two critical parts, ssh-rsa and comment after.

Most people browse to their public file, open in the editor and copy/paste the content into the Bitbucket "access-keys" window. The file is missing that "ssh-rsa" prefix and Bitbucket rejects the key.

Ex:
**ssh-rsa** BBBBBFHHFDS....7 **rsa-key-20220706**

Answer (score 0):

You need to open id_rsa.pub file. Copy all the text (including your email address) and paste it in Key Text Box

[Example SSH input on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcqiR.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just try installing wps2019 and open the .pub on wps2019 and copy the code and paste it :

Answer (score -1):

**Follow the instructions below from scratch and you will be able to sort this issue.**

Many Git servers authenticate using SSH public keys. In order to provide a public key, each user in your system must generate one if they don’t already have one. This process is similar across all operating systems. First, you should check to make sure you don’t already have a key. By default, a user’s SSH keys are stored in that user’s ~/.ssh directory. You can easily check to see if you have a key already by going to that directory and listing the contents:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ls
authorized_keys2  id_dsa       known_hosts
config            id_dsa.pub
```

You’re looking for a pair of files named something like `id_dsa` or `id_rsa` and a matching file with a `.pub` extension. The `.pub` file is your public key, and the other file is the corresponding private key. If you don’t have these files (or you don’t even have a `.ssh` directory), you can create them by running a program called `ssh-keygen`, which is provided with the SSH package on Linux/macOS systems and comes with Git for Windows:

```
$ ssh-keygen -o
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/schacon/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/schacon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
d0:82:24:8e:d7:f1:bb:9b:33:53:96:93:49:da:9b:e3 schacon@mylaptop.local
```

First it confirms where you want to save the key (`.ssh/id_rsa`), and then it asks twice for a passphrase, which you can leave empty if you don’t want to type a password when you use the key. However, if you do use a password, make sure to add the `-o` option; it saves the private key in a format that is more resistant to brute-force password cracking than is the default format. You can also use the `ssh-agent` tool to prevent having to enter the password each time.

Now, each user that does this has to send their public key to you or whoever is administrating the Git server (assuming you’re using an SSH server setup that requires public keys). All they have to do is copy the contents of the `.pub` file and email it. The public keys look something like this:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAklOUpkDHrfHY17SbrmTIpNLTGK9Tjom/BWDSU
GPl+nafzlHDTYW7hdI4yZ5ew18JH4JW9jbhUFrviQzM7xlELEVf4h9lFX5QVkbPppSwg0cda3
Pbv7kOdJ/MTyBlWXFCR+HAo3FXRitBqxiX1nKhXpHAZsMciLq8V6RjsNAQwdsdMFvSlVK/7XA
t3FaoJoAsncM1Q9x5+3V0Ww68/eIFmb1zuUFljQJKprrX88XypNDvjYNby6vw/Pb0rwert/En
mZ+AW4OZPnTPI89ZPmVMLuayrD2cE86Z/il8b+gw3r3+1nKatmIkjn2so1d01QraTlMqVSsbx
NrRFi9wrf+M7Q== schacon@mylaptop.local
```

Comment: Walisson Rodrigues, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

make sure you add an empty space after the ssh key. That solved the issue for me

Answer (score -1):

copy the public key by giving this below command in **Gitbash** terminal

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

you will get a SSH key. paste it in below format with prefix **ssh-rsa** *your ssh key* then **mail id (xyz@gmail.com)** . key will be quite big, so before copy paste key here directly, try to use notepad to maintain the same format, Copy exactly from the end.

> ssh-rsa pasteyourSSHkey xyz@domain.com