# how can i connect GitHub through putty

Tags: github, putty, ssh-keys

I had follow the steps given in so many docs like [this one](http://withcode.com/2013/07/super-easy-ssh-key-setup-for-github-using-putty-on-windows/),
after creating a key i pasted it in my GITHUB account>account settings>SSH key.
When I add it there it shows a message:" key is invalid".

Comment: What did you paste, your public or private key? Did you paste the exact content of the key?

Comment: Also it's better to use GitHub remote with https remote, see [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#https-read-only-and-readwrite---https)

Comment: I have pasted public key

Comment: have you checked [Why might GitHub report a public key as invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10897549) and ["Key is invalid" message on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10476360) ?

Comment: its been done till when i enter the command in the new command prompt window plink git@github.com but it shows a fatal error: no supported authentication and after that i run the pageant.exe than again i try to run the same command but still got the same error

Comment: Have you managed to give your public key to Github?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't link the tutorial part which mentions:

> Save the private key somewhere with a passphrase and then copy the public key text to the clipboard.

"somewhere"? ssh keys must be saved in `%HOME%\.ssh`.
(Note: `%HOME%` doesn't exists in windows, and default to `%USERPROFILE%`)

Make sure to have your public and private keys saves in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa
%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
plink git@github.com
```